# How to update Staus onFacebook User 's frnds wall in blackberry

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I have to post on the Facebook User's friends wall.i m using this code

```
Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as); 
User user = fb.getCurrentUser(); 
User[] friends = user.getFriends(); 
if (friends != null && friends.length > 0) { 
for (int i=0; i if (friends != null && friends.length > 0)   
{
 friends[i].publishStatus("TEsting App");
}
}
```

plz Someone provide the code for that....